# How to load html page into android webview with its associated resources such as image and css files?

Tags: android

Need help here!!

I have all web resources in "/storage/sdcard0/Test" directory as below in android:

1. All css files goes under this dir: /storage/sdcard0/Test/Styles
2. All image files goes under this dir : /storage/sdcard0/Test/Images
3. All html under this dir : /storage/sdcard0/Test/Text

Each of the html file under Text directory uses resources in Styles and Images directory.

I am able to load html page into web view but its associated images are not displayed in a web view.

Here is my code:

```
    WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web_view);

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccessFromFileURLs(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowUniversalAccessFromFileURLs(true);
   File storageDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

    File baseUrl = new File(storageDir, "Test1");

    File text = new File(baseUrl, "Text");

    File file = new File(text, "part0013.xhtml");

    StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        BufferedReader bf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( new FileInputStream(file)));

        String line;
        while((line = bf.readLine())!= null){
            data.append(line);
        }


    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    Log.d("MainActivity", baseUrl.getAbsolutePath().toString());

    webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(baseUrl.getAbsolutePath().toString(), data.toString()
            , "text/html","UTF-8", null);
```

below is my partial html content:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.1//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/DTD/xhtml11.dtd"><html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
<title>Chapter 2. Understanding Views&#8212;The UI Building Blocks</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../Styles/style0001.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="application/vnd.adobe-page-template+xml" href="page-template.xpgt"/>
</head><body>
<h2 id="ch02"><a id="page_23"></a>Chapter 2. Understanding Views&#8212;The UI Building Blocks</h2>
<p class="noindent"><strong>Sometimes it is best to start with the building blocks before diving into much more complex topics, and that is the goal here. This chapter is all about views, which allow your apps to display their content to your users. You will learn all the major view subclasses and gain a fundamental understanding of key attributes such as view IDs, padding, and margins. If you have already built any apps, most of this will be review for you, so feel free to skim through the chapter as you move toward the heart of the book.</strong></p>
<div class="heading">
<h3 id="ch02lev1sec1"><a id="page_24"></a>What Is a View?</h3>
<p class="noindent">Views are the most basic component of the user interface, and they extend the <code>View</code> class. They always occupy a rectangular area (although they can display content of any shape) and can handle both drawing to the screen and events such as being touched. Everything that is displayed on the screen utilizes a view.</p>
<div class="image">
<p class="tab-caption"><a id="ch02tab01"></a><strong>Table 2.1</strong> <code>View</code>&#8217;s Most Commonly Used Attributes</p>
<div class="image"><img src="../Images/image00407.jpeg" alt="Image"/></div>
<div class="image"><img src="../Images/image00408.jpeg" alt="Image"/></div>
<img src="../Images/image00409.jpeg" alt="Image"/></div>"
```

Is there any thing wrong with this code?

Comment: You'll need to share your html that includes the CSS and Images.  You may need to use the file protocol on the URL you're constructing, per the documentation on [loadDataWithBaseURL](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadDataWithBaseURL).

Comment: Hi C. Ross. Not Sure I understand? My html files contain relative url to access its resource.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging code, finally I figured out the solution to do it by simply using loadUrl() method.

```
  webView.loadUrl("file:///" + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

However, the documentation written for loadDataWithBaseURL is little misleading and does not actually load the resource from base directory. In my case, it was referring the parent directory of base directory.